Evolution/Gnome Calendar sync manually with enabled power safe mode
I would like to sync my CalDAV calender using Evolution/Gnome calendar. The problem is, I usually have the power safe mode enabled, so downloading of data is disabled even if I manually try to sync the calenders.
Has someone a Idea to fix this?
I techniaclly could always disable power safe mode to sync the calendar, but this would be verry anoying.
Thanks in advance.

If downloading data is disabled, how do you expect it ever to sync?

I would like to have a way to allow Evolution to manually sync data even if download is generally disabled.
